# Auto-constructor not working with <functional> objects

Tags: c++, constructor

Consider the following code:

```
class _c {
    public:
    _c(int);
    _c(function<void(void)>);
};
```

A class with two constructors defined for an `int` and a `function<void(void)>` respectively.

Which means that I can now instantiante objects of those class like this:

```
_c a = _c(0);
_c b = _c([]() {});
```

Now, I declare a function that takes a `_c` object as an argument:

```
void _f(_c __c) {};
```

And now I can call this function with my `_c` objects like this:

```
_f(_c(0));
_f(_c([]() {}));
```

Until here, everything looks good. Now, if I try to call my `_f` function without explicity invoking the `_c` constructor I see that:

```
_f(0) // works because C++ knows to construct a _c with an 0 by using _c(int)
```

but,

```
_f([]() {}) // fails with 'no matching function for call to _f'
```

I don't understand why is this happening, could someone please explain why doesn't it work when using a `<functional>` type?

Also, I'm compiling with: Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)

Comment: Using token `__c` makes your program ill-formed: `__c` is reserved for your compiler's implementation.  Avoid mimicing the styles of `std` header libraries.

Comment: @Yakk. It is not `__c`. It is just `_c`.

Comment: @Nawaz There are both `__c` and `_c` above.  A simple ctrl-F will find it.

Comment: @Yakk: Ohhh. I see. BTW, it is *unsual* naming, even it is `_c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `f(0)`, the argument is of type `int` which can convert into `_c`. It is *usual* one-step conversion.

However, when you call `_f([]() {})`, the argument is lambda-type (generated by the compiler), not of the type `std::function<void(void)>`. So in this case, it *needs* **two** conversions — one from lambda-type to `std::function<void(void)>`, then to `_c` (using the conversion-constructor).

The two-steps conversion is **not** allowed by the language,which is why your code doesn't work.

The solution is to add a templated constructor as:

```
template<typename Functor, typename =decltype(std::declval<Functor&>()())>
_c(Functor && func);
```

Then your code should work.

Comment: Will want SFINAE, as otherwise we have a perfect-forwarding implicit one-argument ctor, which is bad mojo.  `class=decltype(std::declval<std::decay_t<Functor>&>()())>` upgrade?

Comment: Thanks Nawaz, is there any way to declare a constructor for a 'lamdba-type' ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept the answer as soon as I can. In the meantime, why use `template<class F, class=decltype(std::declval<F&>()())>` instead of just `template<typename Functor> _c(Functor&&);`.

Comment: @almosnow: The second template parameter is used to disallow types other than callable-entity (which takes nothing as argument). For example, if you pass `f(0L)`, then the templated constructor should NOT be called. Read about SFINAE.

Comment: @almosnow the `typename=decltype` is a *test* to determine if the type `F` passed in should be used.  If it can be invoked with an `operator()` with no arguments it passes the test.  If it fails the test, this constructor is not considered a valid one for the type `F`.  Without this test, **any type** (including `_c&` or `int` or `std::map` or `nullptr_t`) would match this constructor, and that isn't good.

Comment: @almosnow No, there is no way to declare a constructor for a 'lambda-type', because it is an implicitly-declared type that can be expected to be unique for each lambda expression.

Comment: @Yakk Ok, so now when I put `template<typename Functor, typename =decltype(std::declval<Functor&>()())>
_c(Functor && func);` on the .h and then I want to implement it later on the .cc file, I get a `template parameter redefines argument` error. I tried googling but couldn't find the syntax for implementing this correctly.

Comment: @almosnow that's not going to work with templates. If you want to have your implementation in a .cpp file you'll want the template constructor to defer to a std::function<> constructor.

Comment: @almosnow either implement in header file, or in header file leave the `std::function` overload intact.  Make the SFINAE one body look like: `_c(Functor&&func):_c(std::function<void()>(std::forward<Functor>(func))){}` to forward to the `std::function` implementation.  Then implement `std::function` ctor in `.cpp` file.

Comment: @Yakk, Richard Hodges, Nawaz; Got it all, thank you very much!

Comment: @Nawaz that unamed SFNAE type check is a new one for me - that's just awesome. I'm writing boost::asio:: rpc_socket objects at the moment - you can imagine how useful that's going to be!! Many thanks.

Comment: @Yakk how would you extend the test for a more complex function type, say `function<int(int, int)>`

Comment: @almosnow enable ifs, is convertible, and decltype.